# SQL Server : Export Data Keys are not creating

Tags: sql-server, data-export

In SQL Server 2014, I want to export data from one database to another database. Those databases are in different servers. Even though I enable identity insert, it is not creating primary or foreign keys.

[image]

Can you help me about this? Why doesn't it create keys?

Comment: Are you trying to move a database or only parts?  Is this single move operation or are you going to be pushing new records only on an interval?

Comment: Actually I am trying to take a similar database in other server. I don't have permission to take backup so I am trying to work around.